# Azure SQL database alert rule when DURATION longer than

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-alerts

I want to create a alert rule if a query on my SQL database takes longer than XXX seconds.

[image]

In the create alert dialog i cannot select a signal named "Duration".

[image]

Can you suggest a solution how to create a alert for **a query taking longer than X seconds**?

Comment: Maybe we can use Azure SQL Analytics, reder this [post](https://www.sqlshack.com/getting-started-with-azure-sql-analytics/). It supports Query duration statistics.

Comment: i was expecting something more standard than using a service to configure a service for a service?

Comment: Hi @Daniel  Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @JosephXu sorry for not responding. Currently i am evaluation your response. I will write a reply after i have solved it. Currently i need to order a "Azure SQL Analytics" resource which currently takes some time...